# projection of plane on a line

Tags: abstract-algebra

In basic algebra by Nathan Jacobson, he said that a plane can be projected to a line. The text states that "if the plane is the domain and a line is co domain,then one maps any point P in the plane on the foot of the perpendicular from P to the given line."

I feel slight difficulty in imagining this. Can anyone help me with a diagram? ..

Comment: What if the plane and the line intersect? How to define perpendicular at the point of intersection?

Comment: For what dimensions?

Comment: Can you explain for both dimensions two and three@mvw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, what is meant is that the line lies within the plane.
An image would be something like this:

[image]

The line is a subset of the plane. All points on the perpendicular are mapped on the intersecting point. So $P,Q,R$ are mapped to $P'$, $S$ is mapped to $S'$ etc.

EDIT: This is very simplified for two dimensions. If I misunderstood, I'll delete the answer.

Comment: I don't think it means the line must lie within the plane.

Comment: Just had a quick look in the book. I believe OP is referring to the introduction of the book, where Jacobson explains what a map is. There it is used as a simple geometric example of how a map can look like, so I think in regard to the introduction of the book, this special case could suffice. In general, of course not.

Comment: But sir Jacobson explains That as a orthogonal projection of plane on a line.If your answer is correct then there are infinite number of projection to a plane isn't it? So I need some clear answer .could you please explain

Comment: Do you mean infinite number of projections from a the plane to any line on the plane?